How to static hedge an up-and-out call option
I am working on a project requiring a static hedging strategy for an up-and-out call option on the S&P 500 option chain. I have tried some strategies but they are not giving strong results in simulations.
I am having a hard time getting close to a strategy and was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I should approach it.
Thank you very much in advance.

The short answer is that you can't statically hedge with European Options.
(btw, you have not told us what instruments are allowed in the static hedge).
If it were possible, then the Local Volatility Model would give you the price. This does not happen because barrier options depend on the full dynamics of the SDE, and not only its fixed time distribution.
A longer answer is that under some conditions one can setup a semi-static hedging strategy: semi because the hedge must be sold if a barrier is touched.
Read this for instance:
https://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/cim/12-13/finance_seminar/Nadtochiy.pdf
and the papers of Carr mentioned in there.

Carr paper is good agree

Thank you so much for your answer. I have the flexibility to utilize any financial instruments to achieve the objectives outlined in the project scope.

"Any" is probably not correct, or you could use (let's say) a call and an up-and-in. Anyway, even if the special conditions for Carr's semi static replication are not met, maybe they reduce the hedging error.
